# UTF-8 Foreign Chars Break When Sent To Facebook/Twitter API's

Tags: javascript, php, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I am using both the Facebook and Twitter OAuth API's to register users and at the same time make a post (written in Korean) to the respective accounts. For Facebook I have opted to us their JavaScript SDK and once integrated everything seems to work fine. For Twitter I have integrated with a popular PHP library and that too works fine.

The problem comes with IE. If I run the registration/posting features in IE then the Korean characters break and become squares or question marks.

I am sure that the PHP, JS and HTML files are all utf-8 encoded and so are my metatags in the header.

With the PHP library I have even tried to encode the string using the `utf8_encode()` function yet the characters still appear.

Is there anything glaring that I am leaving out?

Comment: I know you found it didn't work, but as a tip to you and future readers, don't blindly use `utf8_encode` (or `utf8_decode`) just because "some UTF-8 isn't working right". It specifically converts from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, which is rarely what you want to do.

Comment: I solved it by passing the variable to a cookie in JavaScript and using `encodeURIComponent()` function.